# PostgreSQL 9.0 issues with function

Tags: postgresql

Here is the function I am working with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_multiply_row(_tbl regclass
                                        , _idname text
                                        , _minid int
                                        , _maxid int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN

   EXECUTE (
      SELECT format('INSERT INTO %1$s (%2$I, %3$s)
                     SELECT g.g, %3$s
                     FROM  (SELECT * FROM %1$s LIMIT 1) t
                           ,generate_series($1, $2) g(g)'::text
                   , _tbl
                   , _idname
                   , string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', ')
                   )
      FROM   pg_attribute 
      WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
      AND    attname <> _idname  -- exclude id column
      AND    NOT attisdropped    -- no dropped (dead) columns
      AND    attnum > 0          -- no system columns
      )
   USING _minid, _maxid;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT f_multiply_row('campaign', 'campaign_id', 50, 500);
```

Obviously PSQL 9.0 does NOT have the `format` method (introduced in 9.1), so I am trying to convert the method to *work* in 9.0 and am having the hardest time getting it to work.

`Error : ERROR:  function format(text, regclass, text, text) does not exist
LINE 2:       SELECT format('INSERT INTO %1$s (%2$I, %3$s)
                     ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

So, I attempted to rewrite it in 9.0 style:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_multiply_row()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _tbl regclass := quote_ident('campaign');
    _idname text := 'campaign_id';
    _minid int := 50;
    _maxid int := 500;

BEGIN

   EXECUTE (
      'SELECT INSERT INTO ' || _tbl || ' ($1, $2)
              SELECT g.g $3 FROM (SELECT * FROM ' || _tbl || ' LIMIT 1) t, generate_series($1, $2) g(g)'
        USING _tbl, _idname, string_agg(quote_ident(attname, ', '))
      FROM   pg_attribute 
      WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
      AND    attname <> _idname  -- exclude id column
      AND    NOT attisdropped    -- no dropped (dead) columns
      AND    attnum > 0          -- no system columns
    );

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT f_multiply_row();
```

But, the above causes these two errors:

`Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"
LINE 15:   USING _tbl, _idname, string_agg(quote_ident(attname, ', ')...
           ^`

AND

`Error : ERROR:  function f_multiply_row() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT f_multiply_row()
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Your syntax is wrong in a way that it is hard to interpret the meaning. Try to explain what you want it to achieve. Post an "already built" sql string

Comment: You are making changes _well_ outside the scope of the `format` function. You were on the right track replacing `%1$s` with `' || _tbl || '`. Now do the same with the other two `format` arguments. Don't touch anything else.